# How to use and modify the data uploaded by user by fileinput function

Tags: r, function, shiny

For my application, I ask the user to upload differents dataset. I want, with those, do some work like combine them and modify them (basic manipulation).

I was thinking about reactive function but I don't know how to implement them

```
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Upload 'Contract revenues' (xlsx)",
        multiple = TRUE,
    accept = c(".xlsx")),
tags$hr(),

       fileInput("file2", "Upload 'Mapping Service' (xlsx)",
       multiple = TRUE,
       accept = c(".xlsx")),
tags$hr()
),
mainPanel(
tableOutput("contents")
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(inFile))
       return(NULL)
    file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                                paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
    read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
    })
output$content <- renderTable({
       inFile2 <- input$file2
    if(is.null(inFile2))
       return(NULL)
    file.rename(inFile2$datapath,
                                paste(inFile2$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
    read_excel(paste(inFile2$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
    })  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe you should read a [shiny tutorial first](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/), then.

Comment: Hello, I've build dashboard with shiny but I am trying to stock the file uploaded in variables and I can't :)

Comment: You wrote: "I was thinking about reactive function but I don't know how to implement them". I can help you solve a specific problem. I will not teach you how to implement reactive functions, there are tutorials for that. There are also examples how to use user submitted files. Did you look at the link I gave you? This was just the first page; there is much more on rstudio shiny web sites.

Comment: For example, [read this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html).